# Simple pipeline architecture

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stream, pipeline

I am trying to make sense of the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16505032/136285):

> For example you may have a Source interface and a Sink interface - and
> a Filter abstract class that implements both Source and Sink, as well
> as a Pipe class that implements both Source and Sink and just passes
> the data straight through. This is just one of many ways to name and
> organize such a framework.

I did read that paragraph multiple times, but I think I am missing the whole point here. Could someone please give me a simple c++ implementation of the **above**. My question is really about this specific description, in particular the point about `and a Filter abstract class that implements both Source and Sink` (answer should demonstrate that point).

Here is my current status:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

class Source {
public:
  virtual std::string readsome() = 0;
};

class Sink {
public:
  virtual void writesome(std::string const &s) = 0;
};

class Filter : public Source, public Sink {};
class Pipe : public Source, public Sink {};

class Stdin : public Source {
public:
  std::string readsome() {
    char buf[4096];
    size_t nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, stdin);
    return std::string(buf, nread);
  }
};

class Stdout : public Sink {
public:
  void writesome(std::string const &s) {
    fwrite(s.c_str(), 1, s.size(), stdout);
  }
};

class Tr : public Filter {
  const char From;
  const char To;

public:
  Tr(char from, char to) : From(from), To(to) {}
  std::string readsome() { ... }
  void writesome(std::string const &s) { ... }
};
```

How do I connect `Stdin` to `Tr` to `Stdout` ? Typical `main` function appreciated.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? It looks like you have the C++ implementation bits down, so ... are you asking how to use it? Why this architecture is necessary?

Comment: Can you post a typical `main` function based on the above ?

Comment: The answer doesn't say to use `readsome` and `writesome` functions. It says to design all this stuff yourself, basically.

Comment: one way to implement a filter graph is to *only* have `readsome` or *only* have `writesome` (two different ways depending on which direction is more convenient for you). Then you make it so you call the `readsome` of the last filter or the `writesome` of the first.